# how i can migrate a huawei cloud machine to GCP?

Tags: virtual, migrate

i need a tool or agent, thats help me to migrate several machines from huawei cloud to GCP, can you give me options or only i can do that manually?

i understand that my virtual machine support azure and aws, i think can work with gcp